# Appending text to text area on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, append

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$("#content-styling-bar td").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Bold ") {
    $("#description").append("<b></b>");
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="content-styling-bar">
          <tr>
            <td>
              Bold
            </td>
            <td>
              Italic
            </td>
            <td>
              Underline
            </td>
            <td>
              Main Heading
            </td>
            <td>
              Sub Heading
            </td>
            <td>
              Link
            </td>
            <td>
              Image
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

I have this code. This code is for a site's blog administration. The idea is that when I click on the bold table cell, jQuery gets the text contained in that table cell, and then the script determines which tag-set to append to the textarea.

I prefer the method of comparing the text within the cells to adding unique functions to the `onclick` parameter of each cell because I'd like to keep my code DRY, and that would involve creating a bunch of functions to do basically the same thing, or adding a lot of `onclick` attributes that aren't needed.

I have verified with an elert that I'm indeed getting the text "Bold" when I call `$(this).text()`, but it doesn't seem to satisfy the if statement.

What is the issue with my JavaScript?

Comment: *"What is the issue with my JavaScript?"* We can't tell you, you haven't said what the problem is. What happens, what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't call that DRY at all. You're going to have to repeat all of the text and have a massive if/else statement -- and a fragile one. Instead, I'd use a `data-*` attribute on the cell to store the tag/operation: `<td data-tag="b">Bold</td>` and then `$("#description").append(document.createElement($(this).attr("data-tag")));`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that would work too, but it would cause issues with the `Image` button. That needs to call some additional code so that I can upload the image.

Comment: For complex cases, you branch on the non-presentation attr value, but it automates the common case (`b`, `i`, `u`, `h1`, `h2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have verified with an elert that I'm indeed getting the text "Bold" when I call $(this).text(), but it doesn't seem to satisfy the if statement.
>
> What is the issue with my JavaScript?

Most likely spaces, such as the one you have at the end of the string you're checking (`"Bold "`).

I wouldn't do it that way at all, it's fragile and repetitive, you'll have a huge `if`/`else` and changing presentation text in one place can blow up your code elsewhere. Instead, I'd use a `data-*` attribute:

HTML:

```
<table id="content-styling-bar">
  <tr>
    <td data-tag="b">
      Bold
    </td>
    <td data-tag="i">
      Italic
    </td>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then:

```
$("#content-styling-bar td").click(function() {
    $("#description").append(document.createElement($(this).attr("data-tag")));
});
```

If you have more complex cases, it still gives you something that isn't presentation text to switch on, and it automates the common case:

```
$("#content-styling-bar td").click(function() {
    var tag = $(this).attr("data-tag");
    switch (tag) {
        case "img":
            handleImage();
            break;
        case "a":
            handleLink();
            break;
        default: // "b", "i", "u", "h1", "h2", ...
            $("#description").append(document.createElement(tag));
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).text()` may contain spaces that will ruin your `if` condition.so I think the problem is that. use `$(this).text().trim()` so it would clear spaces. [PLUNCKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/csHYIEVPxoTrUENwX7MM)

```
 $("#content-styling-bar td").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == "Bold") {
  $("#description").append("<b>shirin</b>");
 }
```